# Discharge through a gate - Feedback needed

Tags: pid-control, feedback-loop

I need to make a PI feedback loop for a hydro power plant. The discharge through one gate is given by Q in equation 4.2. I need to keep (regulate) H = 116 m.a.s.l (meters above sea level) where H = H<sub>g</sub> + D/2.

As I understand this, the variables Q, D, and H<sub>g</sub>, in equation (4.1) are functions of time. I need to find the state variables and the control input variables. How should I go around this problem? Should I try to find Laplace equation for this and use the well known feedback equation, or should set it up in state space model?

[image]

What I have done so far is following:

[image]

So the state space form is:

[image]

[image]

I´m not sure if it's okay to choose x_1 = Q^2 / D^2?

Comment: Looks like homework - we are not a free completion service. Show what you have done so far.

Comment: It's not a homework, it's a problem I am dealing with at my job.